# Implement an equation with a subtraction and division of two arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, equation

I want to implement this equation in Matlab
[image]

The a values are in an array of 140x1 double called approx, the values of x are also in an array of 140x1 double called subArray, and n is an array 1x1 with a value equal to 140.

I am using the following code:

```
MRE=(1/n)*(abs(approx(:,1)- subArray(:,1))/abs(subArray(:,1)));
```

but I'm getting the following error

Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

How could I implement this equation in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you want [`element-wise division`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html). Also don't forget the summation:

```matlab
MRE = (1/n) * sum((abs(approx - subArray) ./ abs(subArray)));
              ^^^                         ^
```

Using some random data:

```matlab
clc, clear, rng(3);

n = 140;
approx = rand(n, 1);
subArray = rand(n, 1);

MRE = (1/n) * sum((abs(approx - subArray) ./ abs(subArray)))

% MRE =
% 
%     4.2877
```